# How can I select a single column from a table in SQL Server & put that value into a variable?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Registration` with many columns. I need to get `customer_id` and put that value into a variable for use that in a session for moving & use between ASP Webforms. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExecuteScalar` method to get single column value. Below is a very basic example of how to get single column value.

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Customer_id from Registration", con);
  con.Open();
  string id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

}
```

Here is how you can store the value in session

```
Session["CustomerID"] = id;
```

And here is how you can retrieve the value on second page

```
int ID = 0;
int.TryParse((string)Session["CustomerID"], out ID);
```

Comment: Well,i want Put customer_id in a variable for use in a session . i want use that session in another webform . but i cant do that . 1- how put that variable in a session ? 2- how use that Session for insert to a table?

Comment: Thank you but my customer_id is a integer , how can i work with integer?

Comment: Please put the code in question body not in comments so it is easy to read.

Comment: Sorry , i want Select customer_id from Registration and put that in a sesion for use in another page . this is my code :

Comment: I'd also put the `SqlCommand` into a `using(.....) { .... }` block - just like the `SqlConnection`

Comment: @marc_s yes that's true but OP looks new to this world so for simplicity i didn't write that in `using`